# FRP Lock ON - Mobile was in Bootloop Samsung

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I am having S6 Edge Plus was stuck on Bootloop while updating from 6 to 7.

tried to reflash usign ODIN even after it was stuck on boot logo. there is message says, FRP lock..

I forgot mail ID and my device never turned on . it was stucked on Bootlogo.

I cant even able to flash Recovery.

How do i solve this? FRP bypass

[image: here is the image]

Comment: @beeshyams Different thing. This "FRP lock" is the message you get from the bootloader when OEM Unlocking isn't turned on.

Comment: @beeshyams this is different. i was stucked on boot logo itself